# Can someone explain the parametrization of this circle

Tags: conic-sections, parametrization

Question:

Parametrise the circle $(x-2)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 4$ with radius $2$ centered at $(2,3)$, such that the imaginary particle tracing this circle is travelling in the clockwise direction and at time $t=0$ is at $(0,3)$

My lecturer wrote down:

$x = 2 + 2 \cos(-2 t + \pi)$

$y = 3 + 2 \sin(-2 t + \pi)$

I don't understand how she got the $-2t$ within $\cos$ and $\sin$, I understand the negative sign (clockwise) but not the $2$ (within the trig).

Answer (score 2):

You are right to wonder. The $2$ is arbitrary. That constant adjusts the speed of the particle. There is nothing in the problem statement that leads to that value. It's correct, but so would any other constant.

Comment: I see thanks Ethan! She also wrote down $0\le t\le \pi $and then $0\le 2t\le 2\pi $ What does this mean? Why does t has to be in this range?

Comment: Restricting $t$ to that range parametrizes the curve that is the circle. With weak inequalities at both ends one point is repeated. Allowing any value of $t$ amounts to winding a line around and around the circle. If you  change the constant you can adjust the range accordingly. You can also change the starting point for the range.